# ResourcesNotFoundException when resource available (API 22 and 23 devices)

Tags: android, exception, svg, drawable

I get this crash only on API 22 and 23 devices.

> (android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/show_empty_state.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080156
>                                                                                            at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
>                                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
>                                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
>                                                                                            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:358)
>                                                                                            at com.myProj.utils.EmptyStateView.setImage(EmptyStateView.java:55)
>                                                                                            at com.myProj.tab_two.ShowFragment.onCreateView(ShowFragment.java:111)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)

The resource is definitely there and it works fine on higher devices. The only recent change i did was replace a new vector image using SVG for show_empty_state.
I did look at some other related questions. Could not find an answer so far. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crash was because the vector asset had `gradient` tag for <24 devices.

> android:fillColor
>       Specifies the color used to fill the path. May be
>        a color or, for SDK 24+, a color state list or a gradient color (See 
>       GradientColor and GradientColorItem). If this property is animated, any 
>       value set by the animation will override the original value. No 
>       path fill is drawn if this property is not specified.

Replacing the

```
<gradient android:endX="45300.0" android:endY="-86698.0"
       <android:startX="45300.0" android:startY="-3118.0" android:type="linear">
       <item android:color="#FF1AA186" android:offset="0.0"/>
       <item android:color="#FF23B899" android:offset="1.0"/>
 </gradient>
```

with

```
android:fillColor="#FF1AA186"
```

fixes it.

Better would be to replace the asset with a non-gradient one for <24 sdk.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried all the other srcCompat and other compat gradle options everywhere, but this is the only thing that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that inside path tag of your vector drawable you are using fill color as hexcode rather then any reference to color file.

For example:

You need to use

```
android:fillColor="#FFFFaa"
```

instead of

```
android:fillColor="@color/colorname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:src` with `app:srcCompat`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76179687/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).