# getDrawable NotFoundException on 5.0

Tags: android, vector, resources, drawable

Loading vector drawable, this

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.figure_bp);
```

works fine on devices pre 5.0. On newer APIs it crashes with error

```
Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/figure_wp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070079
```

I have tried with other build versions 25.3.1 ,26 ...

different methods:

```
VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), R.drawable.figure_wp, null);
context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.figure_wp, null);
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.figure_wp);
...
```

Also with `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

always same problem. Sometimes it checks for anydpi first

I have seen most of related questions, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting 3 hours I have figured it out.
Apparently api > 19 && api < 24 can't have gradient tags.
While it should just ignore them, instead it was crashing for me with unrelated error.

Replacing

```
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient android:endX="13760.793757781983"
            android:endY="6638.382661392212"
            android:startX="3736.5152613830564"
            android:startY="6573.006932067871" android:type="linear">
            <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF" android:offset="0.0"/>
            <item android:color="#00FFFFFF" android:offset="1.0"/>
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
```

with

```
android:fillColor = "#FFFFFFFF"
```

fixed the problem. Had to do it manually on all vectors I use, since it was android studio's SVG parser that parsed original svg for me.

Thanks to [ResourcesNotFoundException when resource available (API 22 and 23 devices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688593/resourcesnotfoundexception-when-resource-available-api-22-and-23-devices?rq=1)
for directing me into solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...."
        minSdkVersion ..
        targetSdkVersion ..
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```